# Is there a kind of function in Flex like "input()" in Python?

Tags: python, apache-flex, flex3

I'd like use a similar function to "input()" or "eval()" in Python 3.0 but in Flex, is there it?

Comment: Are you referring to Python 2 or Python 3? The behavior of the `input()` function is different across the two versions. I'm sure you want Python 2's `raw_input()`, which is equivalent to Python 3's `input()`.

Comment: Python 3, I am know about the "input()" metaprogramming function.

Comment: With regard to input I think Sam's answer is addressing that, with regard to eval I think you need to use a library: http://eval.hurlant.com/

Comment: What do you want to *do* in actionscript? No, there is no 'eval', but certain functions that you may want eval for can be performed in other ways in Flex. If you don't tell us what you want, we can only help so much.

Comment: I was looking the easy way to evaluate arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no eval() function in Actionscript 3, but there are libraries you can get that add similar functionality.

Here's one: http://www.riaone.com/products/deval/

Answer (score 1):

`eval()` itself does not exist in flex. However, there is some small level of meta that you're able to do in flex.

For example, if you want the value of variable "myVar1", and it's a public variable, you can refer to it as `this["myVar" + 1]`. You can also call functions in this way, `this["my" + 1 + "func"](...)`

---

In order for a user to give text input in Flex, you want to create a `TextArea` or `TextInput` component. You can then access the component's `.text` property in order to view the text placed in the component.

```
<mx:TextArea id="textarea" text="Start Typing Here" change="changefunc(event)"/>
...
<mx:Script>
    public function changefunc(e:Event):void {
        trace(textarea.text)
    }
</mx:Script>
```